# Internship query

Tags: interviewing, internship, startup

I am pretty good computer engineer, well that's what I believe. I have worked as a freelancer for quite a few time and have a good respect among my peers and my clients. I have been part of many successful websites and android apps. More importantly , I am lead web and android developer at my own startup.

For the past few days, I have been trying to bag an internship and luckily I have even received an offer from a startup. But the problem is the expected salary is not up to the mark. Moreover, interviews for campus placements are around the corner. But the problem with campus placements is that neither are they attractive nor do they cater to tastes and capabilities to the students.

So, I want to ask is whether to accept the offer, or should I continue looking for other offers, or should I look forward for the campus placements.If I were to accept any offer , how can I negotiate with them and cut a pretty handsome deal.

Comment: "internship" and "cut a pretty handsome deal" do not really belong in the same discussion. If you have significant experience and you're looking for higher pay, why are you looking at internships at all?

Comment: Well, I think you didn't get me quite right @Brandin. I am looking for internship to further nurture, polish my skills. Moreover it will help me with establishing connections.

Comment: @RooparshKalia No, either you are not giveing us all relavant Information or you are expecting to much from an internship. If you have the experience that you claim, go get a Job not an internship. Otherwise set your priorities straight.

Comment: Campus placements are not meant to be attractive or cater to the tastes of students.  They are intended to get qualified candidates to do real work that the employers need done.  If you are lucky you can have both, but the are about the employer's needs first.

Comment: *Everybody* is lead developer at their own startup.

Comment: Let's see ... you want an internship that gives you a good salary, caters to your tastes and capabilities, *and* further nurture and polish your skills. Good luck with that. If you come across any such offer, let me know if the company has any job openings for a more senior role (such as, Software Architect). :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Benefits of an internship over a "real" job:**

- It gives you an opportunity for work experience if you are not yet fully qualified to get a position in the field.
- It is short-term and designed to fit in with your education.

That's pretty much it.  If you can land an actual job in the field that fits your circumstances, it should give you all of the benefits of an internship (and more).

So, given that you state that you already have extensive experience, **look for jobs or freelance work.**  If you can find something, it will give you all of the benefits of an internship, while paying more money.

On the other hand, **if the internship is the best employment opportunity you can find, take it.**  You might be able to negotiate somewhat higher pay based on your experience (it's worth a try, anyway), but don't expect too much: internships are low paying, that's just how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at your resume:

> - I have worked as a freelancer for quite a few time and have a good respect among my peers and my clients.
> - I have been part of many successful websites and android apps.More importantly ,
> - I am lead web and android developer at my own startup.

If these can be backed up and fully described; why do you want an internship? why wouldn't you take the time between school sessions to continue freelance and run your startup?

Of course if it is school requirement to compete an internship then by all means get an internship.

As to getting a job instead of an internship, I would be hesitant to hire a student who has an outside company and freelances, for anything else besides and internship. The time window that you can dedicate to my company is short, and once school starts up again you would be gone.

Most companies don't negotiate sweet deals with interns. They have no incentive to. In your situation  pick the first company that would meet the requirements of the program I was in; and that would pay enough  to live off of. Or if there are no requirements go back to my startup.